# Project notification on / off

Tags: github

I am using enterprise version of github and I would like to turn on notification of changes on kanban (projects) board. I cannot google it, is there any possibility to turn on such notifications?

Comment: Currently, it's not possible to turn on notifications for moving cards between the columns. There is only Activity section on `Menu` in Project Board.